# SQL code to get min,max at a time

Tags: time, max, min, ata

How to display min and max salary from a table at a time (2 records at a time, one with max and another with min)?

My input table data:

```
empid  ename sal
1       A    2000
2       B    1000
3       C    1500
4       D    5000
5       E    7000
```

Output:

```
sal
7000 -- max
2000 -- min
```

Comment: I've improved the formatting (for better reading). What did you try already? Show your code attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use a `Union`:

```
Select MAX(Sal)
From TableA

UNION ALL

Select Min(Sal)
From TableA
```

This would give you your desired output:

```
sal
7000 -- max
2000 -- min
```

More information on Unions can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
select max(sal) sal from my_table union all select min(sal) sal from my_table
```